# Django FormView is valid but I need to add_error and return same view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

This is a custom login view I wrote cause I need to login the user with his email, not with his username.

```
class LoginUser(FormView):
    """
    Login with email
    """
    template_name = "profiles/login.html"
    form_class = LoginForm 
    success_url = reverse_lazy("client:profile")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user_email = form.cleaned_data['user_email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']

        user_object = User.objects.get(email=user_email)
        user = authenticate(username=user_object.username, password=password)

        # !!! Problem here when user is None

        login(self.request, user)

        return super(LoginUser, self).form_valid(form)
```

When `user` is `None`, i.e the `authenticate` method returned `None` cause the password was wrong. I need to add an error and return the same view but with the error: "wrong username or password". How can I achieve that using Class Based Views? (I normally use function based views but this time I decided otherwise).

**Edit**

Sayse answer to this question works partially, it correctly moves the validation logic to the `clean` method. But now I get the error

> Django-AttributeError 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

That error happens when there is a call to `login` on a user object without calling `authenticate` on that user object first. Should I put the `login` call inside the `clean` method?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to call `authenticate` in your `LoginForm`'s `clean` method? I think `form_valid` is only called when the form is valid.

Comment: @ShangWang - Would you might making your comment an answer? its correct and I don't really want to take the credit for it

Comment: @Sayse: That's OK. As long as your answer helped(after all I didn't spend as much time as you do to write the answer :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shang Wang notes in the comments, you should be doing this kind of stuff in the form's clean method, but in order to do that you'll need to pass through the request object.

FormView

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(LoginUser, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return kwargs
```

LoginForm

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
    super(LoginForm , self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now you'll be able to call authenticate in the form's clean method.

```
authenticate(username=self.request.user.username, password=password)
```

---

All the above is irrelevant and overkill, you only need to move your logic into the form's clean method

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(LoginForm , self).clean()
    user_email = cleaned_data['user_email']
    subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

    user_object = User.objects.get(email=user_email)
    user = authenticate(username=user_object.username, password=password)
    if user is None:
         self.add_error('user_email', 'Invalid Password')
```

Comment: Note: you could just pass through the user.. You also don't specify what `correo`  is

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'lll test it and then accept it. `correo` is a mistake, already corrected it. I translated the code to english so that it is more confortable to read for people in SO.

Comment: @alejoss - Oh your update makes it even easier then, you just need to use the form clean method

Comment: The solution works partially, now I get a new error I explain on the Edit I just added. What is your opinion about it? Thanks a lot for the help